# I try to delete the recyclerView list from my app and FireStore in Kotlin Android. How can ı call the remove code in my Adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin

ı am a new about Kotlin Android. I add the delete button on my app to delete recyclerView. When I click this button, ı want to to delete from recyclerview list and also from my firestore. I create setonclick listener but when ı click the delete button, it does not work. What do I miss ? What should I do? I shared below my adapter code and you can see easily what ı miss

```
class NoteAdapter(private var titleText: ArrayList<String>, private var imageButton: ArrayList<String>, private var noteText: ArrayList<String>, private var onClickListener : OnClickListener? = null) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    fun setOnClickListener(onClickListener: OnClickListener){
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener
    }

    interface OnClickListener {
        fun onClick(position: Int){
        }
    }

    private fun removeItem(position: Int){
        arrayListOf<NoteAdapter>().removeAt(position)
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
    }


    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val itemTitle : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerTitleText)
        val itemImage : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerImage)
        val itemDelete : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete)


        init {

            itemView.setOnClickListener { v: View ->


               // Toast.makeText(itemView.context,"You clicked on item # ${position + 1}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                val intent = Intent(itemView.context, PastNotesActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("oldTitle", titleText[position])
                intent.putExtra("oldNote", noteText[position])
                intent.putExtra("oldImage", imageButton[position])
                itemView.context.startActivity(intent)

            }


        }
    }




    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_row, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.itemTitle.text = titleText[position]
        Picasso.get().load(imageButton[position]).resize(150,150).into(holder.itemImage)
        holder.itemView.delete.setOnClickListener {
            if(onClickListener!= null) {

                onClickListener!!.onClick(position)

                removeItem(position)

            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return titleText.size
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the delete functionality from firestore and listen for value update listener and update your adapter in valueupdate listener like bellow.

```
    db.collection("table").document("row1")
        .delete()
        .addOnSuccessListener { 
               // Update your adapter here.
               Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully deleted!") 
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w(TAG, "Error deleting document", e) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,you can your interface listener inside of your adapter. For example.

```
interface OnClick{
        fun onItemClickListener(v:View, pos:Int, item:Any)
    }
```

Then this listener give to adapter constructor.

```
class NoteAdapter(val listener:OnClick)
```

Then call the this listener inside of activity class. You can do the deletion here.

```
adapter = NoteAdapter(object : NoteAdapter.OnClick {
                override fun onItemClickListener(v: View, pos:Int, data: Any){
       where(v.id){
         R.id.itemDelete-> deleteItem(data)
      }
    })
```

You can delete it from firestore as @VishalPawar said in the comment above. This procces inside ofOnclickListener.

```
fun deleteItem(data:Any){

    db.collection("table").document("${data.id}")
            .delete()
            .addOnSuccessListener { 
                   // Update your adapter here.
                   Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully deleted!") 
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w(TAG, "Error deleting document", e) }

}
```

I am sharing the above comment with reference to it again.

I hope so this answer of your questions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer,  but I editted the code, can you check again ? (Teşekkürler)